# Simple M/M/1 Queuing Simulation with SimPy, Departure Placement Issue

Tags: python, statistics, simulation

I am looking forward to doing a simple M/M/1 queuing simulation, later I would like to focus on M/M/C models, and generalize more results further. Initially, I started from a more complex model, which includes reneging customers as well, and here is the post [How to calculate the average times of M/M/1 system in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73304616/how-to-calculate-the-average-times-of-m-m-1-system-in-python/73347859?noredirect=1#comment129554945_73347859) . However, when I tried to simplify it into a simple M/M/1 system, I see in the console part that the customers are arriving in the right way, however, they do not depart from the system accordingly. For instance, initially, Customer 00 arrives and departs. Later Customer 01 arrives, Customer 02 and so on, nevertheless, the departure placement is incorrect.

You may see my code below, I will be glad if you are able to assist me.

```
import random
import simpy
import numpy
from random import seed
import statistics
seed(29384)  # for seed of randint function
random_seed = 42  # for seed of other random generators
new_customers = 10  # Total number of customers in the system
interarrival = numpy.random.poisson(6, size=None)  # Generate new customers roughly every x seconds
waitingTimes = []
serviceTimes = []
interarrivalTimes = []

def generator(env, number, interval, server):  # customer generator with interarrival times.
    """generator generates customers randomly"""
    for i in range(number):
        c = customer(env, 'Customer%02d' % i, server, service_time=random.expovariate(0.15))
        env.process(c)
        t = random.expovariate(1.0 / interval)
        yield env.timeout(t)  # adds time to the counter, does not delete from the memory

def customer(env, name, server, service_time):
    # customer arrives to the system, waits and leaves
    arrive = env.now
    print('%7.4f : Arrival time of %s' % (arrive, name))
    with server.request() as req:
        results = yield req | env.timeout(arrive)
        
        if req in results:
            servertime = service_time
            yield env.timeout(servertime)
            serviceTimes.append(servertime)
            print('%7.4f Departure Time of %s' % (env.now, name))
            print('%7.4f Time Spent in the system of %s' % (env.now - arrive, name))
        else:
            waiting_time = env.now - arrive
            waitingTimes.append(waiting_time)
            print('%6.3f Waiting time of %s' % (waiting_time, name))

random.seed(random_seed)
env = simpy.Environment()
server = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)  # capacity changes the number of generators in the system.
env.process(generator(env, new_customers, interarrival, server))
env.run()
interarrivalTimes.append(interarrival)
average_interarrival = statistics.mean(interarrivalTimes)
average_waitingTime = statistics.mean(waitingTimes)
average_serviceTime = statistics.mean(serviceTimes)
print("Average Interravial Time Is : %7.4f" % (average_interarrival))
print("Average Waiting Time Is : %7.4f" % (average_waitingTime))
print("Average Service Time Is : %7.4f" % (average_serviceTime))

print("Elements of given array: ")
for i in range(0, len(interarrivalTimes)):
    print(interarrivalTimes[i]),
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of `simpy`—tracing its logic reminds me of an [old CS joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMEFROM)—so I'm going to suggest a couple of alternatives.

#### Option 1

If all you want is a basic M/M/1 queue, you don't need anything fancier than a loop-based solution:

```python
from numpy.random import default_rng
import sys

def mm1(arrival_rate, service_rate, n, seed = 1234567):
    rng = default_rng(seed)
    arrive = depart = 0.0
    mean_interarrival_time = 1.0 / arrival_rate
    mean_service_time = 1.0 / service_rate
    print("customer_number,delay_in_queue")
    for customer in range(1, n + 1):
        arrive += rng.exponential(mean_interarrival_time)
        start = max(arrive, depart)
        depart = start + rng.exponential(mean_service_time)
        print("%d,%f" % (customer, start - arrive))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        mm1(float(sys.argv[1]), float(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3]))
    else:
        m1 = "Please specify arrival rate, per-server service rate, and"
        m2 = "# customers separated by spaces on the command-line."
        m3 = "Example: python %s 0.95 1.0 20" % sys.argv[0]
        print("\n\t" + m1, file = sys.stderr)
        print("\t" + m2 + "\n", file = sys.stderr)
        print("\t" + m3 + "\n", file = sys.stderr)
```

Note that this code uses `numpy`'s recommended new [Random Generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) API. The `mm1` function is parameterized to use rates while the `numpy` generator is parameterized to use the mean, so the rates have to be converted via inversion prior to use in the `rng.exponential()` calls. An imaginary zero<sup>th</sup> customer initializes state variables `start` and `depart` to 0.

The logic of the loop is that

- a given customer arrives an exponentially distributed amount of time after the prior arrival;
- the customer starts service either at their own arrival time, or at the departure time of the prior customer, whichever is larger—you can't start until the previous person is finished; and
- the customer departs t<sub>d</sub> time units after starting service, where t<sub>d</sub> is an exponentially distributed service time.
  The difference between `start` and `arrival` is the amount of time the customer spent waiting in line.

#### Option 2

If you plan to add complexity to the model, you'll want to use a suitable modeling framework. As already mentioned, I'm not a fan of `simpy` and instead prefer the [Event Graph](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/182.358460) modeling paradigm published by Lee Schruben back in 1983. In the intervening years the name has morphed to [Event Relationship Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_relationship_graph).

The code below is implemented using [SimpleKit](https://github.com/PaulSanchez/SimpleKit-Python.git), a freely available (MIT License) discrete event scheduling engine written in Python. The linked GitHub repository contains `simplekit.py`, the model engine; several demo models; and `SimulationBasics.pdf`, which started life as a general tutorial for the 2007 Winter Simulation Conference but has been extended to include details about SimpleKit. Head straight to section 5 if you want to skip over the background and leap straight to event graphs and SimpleKit.

The code below is a tweaked version of the `MMk.py` demo code provided in the GitHub repository and described in detail in the tutorial file. It has been modified to focus on reporting customer delays in queue.

```python
"""Demo model of SimpleKit usage."""
from simplekit import SimpleKit
from collections import deque
from numpy.random import default_rng
import sys

class MMk(SimpleKit):
    """Implementation of an M/M/k queueing model using SimpleKit."""

    def __init__(self, arrivalRate, serviceRate, maxServers, numCustomers, seed = 1234567):
        """Construct an instance of the M/M/k."""
        SimpleKit.__init__(self)
        self.mean_interarrival_timeTime = 1.0 / arrivalRate
        self.mean_service_time = 1.0 / serviceRate
        self.maxServers = maxServers
        self.numCustomers = numCustomers
        self.queue = deque()
        self.rng = default_rng(seed)

    def init(self):
        """Initialize all state variables, schedule first arrival and halt."""
        self.numAvailableServers = self.maxServers
        self.customer_number = 0
        self.queue.clear()
        self.schedule(self.arrival, self.rng.exponential(self.mean_interarrival_timeTime))
        print("customer#,delay_in_queue")

    def arrival(self):
        """Add customer to queue, schedule next arrival, beginService if possible."""
        self.customer_number += 1
        self.queue.append((self.customer_number, self.model_time))
        if self.customer_number < self.numCustomers:
            self.schedule(self.arrival, self.rng.exponential(self.mean_interarrival_timeTime))
        if self.numAvailableServers > 0:
            self.schedule(self.beginService, 0.0, priority = 2)

    def beginService(self):
        """Remove customer from line, allocate server, schedule endService."""
        customer, arrival_time = self.queue.popleft()
        print("%d,%f" % (customer, self.model_time - arrival_time))
        self.numAvailableServers -= 1
        self.schedule(self.endService, self.rng.exponential(self.mean_service_time))

    def endService(self):
        """Free server, if customers are waiting initiate another service."""
        self.numAvailableServers += 1
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            self.schedule(self.beginService, 0.0, priority = 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Instantiate and run a copy of the MMk model.
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        MMk(4.5, 1.0, 5, 100).run()
    elif len(sys.argv) == 5:
        MMk(float(sys.argv[1]), float(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3]), int(sys.argv[4])).run()
    else:
        m1 = "Please specify arrival rate, per-server service rate, # servers,"
        m2 = "and # customers separated by spaces on the command-line."
        m3 = "If no arguments are given, these default to: 4.5 1.0 5 100"
        print("\n\t" + m1, file = sys.stderr)
        print("\t" + m2, file = sys.stderr)
        print("\n\t" + m3 + "\n", file = sys.stderr)
```

Obviously this can be used as an M/M/1 queue by setting `k`, the number of servers, to 1.

Place your model and `simplekit.py` in the same directory/folder, and you should be ready to go. I called the model file `MMk_delays.py` and put it in a directory called `TestSimpleKit`:

```text
TestSimpleKit
├── MMk_delays.py
└── simplekit.py
```

I could then run it with default parameters by typing `python3 MMk_delays.py`.

Comment: Hello, I am really thankful for your response! The second option is really beneficial, however, I am having trouble while running it, which says ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleKit' from 'simplekit'. I have already installed the simplekit library, I understood the logic behind of it, which is way better than simpy.

Comment: Did you place the model and simplekit.py in the same folder?

Comment: Oh okay, solved the issue thank you! I have got one more question, since it is doing a Discrete Event Simulation, and there are many types of it, such as FIFO and LIFO, how can I understand my model is using that approach, could you please enlighten me?

Comment: `self.queue.append((self.customer_number, self.model_time))` in the `arrival` event combined with `self.queue.popleft()` in the `beginService` makes it FIFO. Replace `popleft()` with `pop()` to get LIFO behavior. In other words, it's just python, so python logic applies to all classes you opt to use in your model, such as containers or random variate generation. You can either make that edit in a separate copy of the program, or modify the program to take an `argv` flag which changes whether you use FIFO or LIFO logic based on an `if/else` statement.

Comment: A code smells in SimPy is that it uses exception handling for branching behavior that is entirely unexceptional.